# Trying to conditionally format CORREL( in excel with an IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, correlation

in column A, there are long dates with hours.

I am trying to only run correlation on hours 10-17 (out of 24 total hours in day)

Want to search column A with dates for the specific hours and correlate between two other columns matching the filtering criteria.

I thought about using correl(IF(Hour
Functions let me know if anyone has a better idea

Trying to take A2:A7125 filter out just those specific hours and then correlated C2:C7125 with D2:D7125 for only hours 10-17

Tried Correl(IF(Hour(A2:A7125 not sure how to filter past this point

Comment: Use FILTER on ranges in columns C and D with condition of hour of column A greater than or equal to 10 and smaller than (or equal to?) 17. CORREL on the filtered ranges.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.